# Parsing/Splitting a string doesn't return all the parts

Tags: arrays, string, delphi

I have a procedure that I found from another question that supposedly splits/delimits a string , when provided a string, a delimiter, and and a TStrings list. That procedure is:

```
procedure SplitString(const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
  //Delimits or splits the received string, returns TStrings array
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;
```

However when I provided it this:

```
SplitString('=',test,EqualParse);
```

Where `test` is a string `200  : NCPATH -------------> = C:\SNDATA\NC\` and `EqualParse` is a `TStringList`, all that I get back is `200` for `EqualParse[0]` (which should be everything to the left of the equal sign. I am expecting to get back `200  : NCPATH ------------->`. Is there something wrong with how I am using that code? Can I modify is to also not split by a space if not explicitly done?

Comment: Personally I find the idea of instantiating `TStringList` just to split a string to be rather unpalatable. So, I have my own function that receives string, delimiter and returns `TArray<string>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `TStrings.StrictDelimiter` to True, otherwise `DelimitedText` includes whitespace as a delimiter.

```
procedure SplitString(const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
  //Delimits or splits the received string, returns TStrings array
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.StrictDelimiter := True; // <-- add this
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;
```

This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText):

> If StrictDelimiter is set to False, the space character is also interpreted as a delimiter, regardless of the value of Delimiter.

With that said, setting the delimiter properties of the input `TStrings` may have unwanted  side effects on the caller, so I would suggest using a local `TStringList` for the parsing:

```
procedure SplitString(const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
var
  Tmp: TStringList;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
  tmp := TStringList.Create;
  try
    tmp.Delimiter := Delimiter;
    tmp.StrictDelimiter := True;
    tmp.DelimitedText := Input;
    Strings.Assign(tmp);
  finally
    tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 The assertion is rather pointless. View `Strings.Assign()` as an assertion that `Strings` is assigned. Code would rapidly fill up with `Assert(Assigned(...))` if we attempted to add such an assertion for all methods that received objects as parameters.